# New MacBook macOS client won’t connect to PC host. Old MacBook connects fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac

I have been using Synergy with my PC (host) and my MacBook (client) without issue. I got a new MacBook and am trying to set it up as the new client. I know that the IP address for the host is correct because it works on my old MacBook (and is in the same format `192.168.0.xx` as the IP address for the client). I get a pop up with error:

> “Connection failed. Check the IP address on the server, your TLS and firewall settings.”

The firewall is turned off on my MacBook. I have added the new MacBook under “Configure Server” on the host and verified that the computer name is correct. I've rebooted both machines and the router. The old MacBook connects and works fine, but the new mac continues to fail.

[image: Screenshot.]

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: What version of TLS is Synergy using? macOS 12 will not longer use 1.0 or 1.1. Your first image shows TLS is disabled - is this just for troubleshooting?

Comment: TLS has always been disabled while running synergy on my old mac (I have Syngery Basic, not pro. TLS encryption requires Synergy Pro). I did not change any settings on the host, I just added the new client. My new mac client is on Big Sur 11.6.2. I've allowed Synergy under System Preferences> Security and Privacy: Input Monitoring, Full Disk Access, and Accessibility.